# Use of "confess" when followed by interrogative clause (e.g. I confessed to my parents what I ate last night)

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, questions, complements

I am not a native speaker, but just wondering if you can use a non-why question as the embedding clause of *confess*.

> **a.** I confessed to my wife why I started smoking again.

(Pretty sure this one with why-question is grammatical, right?)

What about:

> **b.** I confessed to my parents what I ate last night.

(Suppose that my parents do not let me eat junk food, but last night I ate potato chips secretly and felt guilty about it.)

> **c.** I want to confess to my parents what I ate last night.

(Same context as (b))

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

*Confess* in the sense of admitting to a transgression licenses a prepositional phrase with *to* as a complement defining the transgression. The object of the preposition can be any noun phrase. Thus

> **[1a]** He confessed to **assault**. (noun)
>   **[1b]** He confessed to **cheating**.(participle)
>   **[1c]** He confessed to **whatever he remembered**. (clause)

So there's no grammatical barrier to your examples **a.** and **b.** (In your example **c.**, you've changed the wording so that *confess* is part of a non-finite clause -- in fact, an infinitive clause -- instead of being the verb of the independent clause. But that doesn't change the complementary *to* prepositional phrase.)

Semantically, however, you confess to a bad act, so it's a little strange to confess to the *reason* for a bad act. But consider the following scenario.

> Last night when my wife confronted me with the pack of cigarets that I
>   thought I'd hidden, I confessed to my her **why I had started smoking
>   again**. "Honey," I said. "I'm sleeping with your sister, and she likes
>   to smoke after sex. I didn't want her to feel uncomfortable smoking
>   alone."

Comment: Very clear, thank you!  Just one follow-up question: "confess" can be followed by declarative complements too, right? e.g. I confessed / want to confess that I've been sleeping with your sister.

Comment: And also noun phrases: *He confessed his guilt* or *He confessed an abiding love for dahlias*. Or is this merely an ellipsis of the "to" in the respective prepositional phrases?